# Flutter authstate intefering with my bottom bar(firebase)

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin

Hi guys i am new to `flutter`,I am having a problem with `authstate`. I am unable to select other items in my bottom navigation bar. Everytime i click on an item it keeps going back to the first item:
    Here is some code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
          FirebaseUser user = snapshot.data;
          if (user == null) {
            return SignInPage();
          }
          return HomePage();
        } else {
          return Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

Homepage has a bottom navbar:

```
 Scaffold Homepage() {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: PageView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Timeline(currentUser: currentUser),
          ActivityFeed(),
           Upload(currentUser: currentUser),
          // Discussions(currentUser: currentUser),
          Learn(),
          Profile(profileId: currentUser?.id),
        ],
        controller: _pageController,
        onPageChanged: onPageChanged,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      ),


    bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavyBar(
   selectedIndex: pageIndex,
   showElevation: true, // use this to remove appBar's elevation
   onItemSelected: (index) => setState(() {
              pageIndex = index;
              _pageController.animateToPage(index,
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.ease);
    }),
   items: [
     BottomNavyBarItem(
       icon: Icon(Icons.whatshot),
       title: Text('Home'),
       activeColor: Colors.deepOrange,
     ),
     BottomNavyBarItem(
         icon: Icon(Icons.notifications_active),
         title: Text('Notification'),
         activeColor: Colors.deepOrange,
     ),
       BottomNavyBarItem(
         icon: Icon(Icons.photo_camera),
         title: Text('Upload'),
         activeColor: Colors.deepOrange,
     ),
     BottomNavyBarItem(
         icon: Icon(Icons.rss_feed),
         title: Text('Articles'),
         activeColor: Colors.deepOrange,
     ),
     BottomNavyBarItem(
         icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
         title: Text('Profile'),
         activeColor: Colors.deepOrange,
     ),
   ],
),
```

SO everytime i click on an item on the bottom bar to go to another page,i keep being redirected to the first item(page)

Comment: Hello Hosea. Welcome to StackOverflow. These Widgets called BottomNavyBar and BottomNavyBarItem are your own custom widgets, or from a package? This issue doesn't seem to have a relation with your AuthState. Does your BottomNavigationBar work separately from the rest of your Firebase code?

Comment: It's from here @JoãoSoares https://pub.dev/packages/bottom_navy_bar

Comment: Where do you define `pageIndex`?

Comment: We can't see all of the code involved in this problem. Can you share the variable declarations as the previous commenter asked?